# How to install those base00-base0F colors on Bash terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, colors

I have the following list of colors that I want to use on my bash terminal:

```
.base00 { color: #2b303b; }
.base01 { color: #343d46; }
.base02 { color: #4f5b66; }
.base03 { color: #65737e; }
.base04 { color: #a7adba; }
.base05 { color: #c0c5ce; }
.base06 { color: #dfe1e8; }
.base07 { color: #eff1f5; }
.base08 { color: #bf616a; }
.base09 { color: #d08770; }
.base0A { color: #ebcb8b; }
.base0B { color: #a3be8c; }
.base0C { color: #96b5b4; }
.base0D { color: #8fa1b3; }
.base0E { color: #b48ead; }
.base0F { color: #ab7967; }
```

How can I install them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom terminal profile

Open a terminal (KDE/Plasma, Edit->Profiles: Gnome Edit->Profile preferences)

And set whatever colors you like.

If you're in a TTY terminal `setterm` will change foreground/background colors ie. `setterm -foreground black -background white`. Also you don't "install" colors, you'll need to use ANSI escape sequences to set colors. See this comprehensive reference [Bash tips: Colors and formatting (ANSI/VT100 Control sequences)](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Comment: That's not really my case, this is pure bash, no terminal emulator so your answer doesn't really fit.

Comment: Ok so you're in a tty right? `setterm` will change foreground/background colors ie. `setterm -foreground black -background white`. Also you don't "install" colors, you'll need to use ANSI escape sequences to set colors. See this comprehensive reference [http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, could you please edit your answer and put this, so I can mark it as the solution?